# Problem with passing cck field as argument in drupal view

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I am not quite sure of what i am doing wrong, basically in my view ui, i passed a cck field called day as argument, i selected "Provide default argument" and entered the phpcode below after selecting the php code option. What i am trying to achieve is that if the user enters day1 for example in the live preview, only information relating to that day should be displayed however, i am not sure what i am doing wrong?

```
    $numDays=7; 
    for($i=0; $i<$numDays; $i++) { 
        $futuredate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+' . strval($i) . ' days'));
        return "day"$i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please explain what your logic is attempting to do? As it's coded it will only return "day0" - there is no conditional statement in your loop, so it's going to hit the line that says return on the first iteration every time. I assume you want to provide a default argument based on whatever the current date is? If so you can get the current day of a week as a number with the date function. I'm guessing you're looking for something like this (this is all you need in your code):

```
return 'day' . date('w', time());
```

That'll return "dayX" where X is the current day of the week if an argument isn't provided.